# Basic authentication via postman doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I need to send a get-request to the address localhost:8080/users. I want to use basic authentication. When I enter the necessary credentials and send the request postman redirects me to the login page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share a simple reproductive example of something related that will help us to give you the reason or a solution to the problem ?

Comment: In fields username and password I enter the correct credentials and url-address and press send. But, instead of getting the necessary result, I am redirected to login page with response 200 OK.

Comment: Please provide a code that you have implemented in `SecurityFilterChain` bean, because without it I couldn’t help you.

Comment: Sure, it should be as a update of the question

Comment: @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()

                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/users", "/users/{userId}") .and()
                .formLogin()
                
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
                .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")